# how do I edit a ~/.git/config file using a text editor?

Tags: git, ssh

I'm going through the [bitbucket tutorial](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678) for setting up SSH for git.  In the image below, I am stuck at step 7.2 for git users: "Edit the ~/repos/bb101repo-pratice/.git/config file with your favorite editor."

The problem is that I don't know how to access that file and open it in an editor.  I have tried entering "cd ~/repos/bb101repo-pratice/.git/config" into my terminal, but the terminal says that file does not exist.  I have also tried using spotlite and finder, but to no avail.

How do i access the file, and then once I do, how do I edit it using an editor?

My "favorite editor" is sublime text 3, and I am running mackericks on a mackbook.

Comment: Open the file in `<your home directory>/repos/bb101repo-pratice/.git/config` with any editor you prefer?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear.  The file I named is not available in my finder, so I guess I need to open it from the command line, but I don't know how.

Comment: Note that `config` (the local config of a Git repo) is a file, not a folder: `"cd ~/repos/bb101repo-pratice/.git/config` will always fail (you cannot 'cd' change directory into a file)

Comment: @VONC, I'm a little confused.  In my question, I call it a file.  I never call it a folder...could you clarify or elaborate on your insight?

Comment: @Goodword you cannot 'cd' into a file: it is not a directory. cd is for changing directory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't even have to edit it manually.

Simply type (using a [`git remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) command):

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:newuserme/bb101repo.git
```

You can then, if you want, cat the file to check its content:

```
cat <your home directory>/repos/bb101repo-pratice/.git/config
```

To edit:

```
git config --local --edit
```

Comment: Awesome, this worked.  Just wondering though, how would I bring up this file in an editor?  ~/.git/config is not visible in my finder

Comment: You can type, depending on what your `$EDITOR` environment variable is set: `git config --local --edit`

Comment: note, I had to remove the 'answered' tag, because, while your solution allowed me to move forward, and I am very grateful, it didn't answer the question, which is "how do I edit the file?"

Comment: that's a different answer, but I'll hit you with the tag again, because that actually seems to answer the question.  Thank you so much.